# Configuring RepositoryRestResource to Encrypt User Password

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest

How would I configure my RepositoryRestResource to encrypt passwords coming in for my User class?

I have the JWT auth set up using the password encoder bean in my "WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter" class.

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws 
Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userSecurityService).passwordEncoder(encoder());
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

My repository is as follows

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "user", path = "user")
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
User findByUsername(@Param("username") String name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming login/signup data is transmitted over HTTPS (TLS)..

> How would I configure my RepositoryRestResource to encrypt passwords coming in for my User class?

RepositoryRestResource deals with REST and has nothing to do with encrypting password in the backend. Just autowire in your PasswordEncoder bean and when you set your domain User's password, like such: `userToBeSaved.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(inputUser.getPassword()))`, before you save the entity to the database. And then You should get a hashed password in your database.

Comment: Where should I be setting the users password?

Comment: An end user sets/enters his password in whatever signup/login form you implemented, but it's up to you to hash the user's password in the backend during the registration process. This typically happens in your service layer where you need to persist your user.